# how to check which of union's field is chosen in TTCN

Tags: ttcn

I have this snippet of TTCN code:

```
type union MyUnion {
    integer kuku,
    charstring ryku
}
(...)
var MyUnion unia;
unia.kuku := 15;
```

Now I want to check which of union field(`kuku` or `ryku`) is set. How can I achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the ischosen() function.

Example:

```
if ( ischosen(unia.kuku) ) {
    log("kuku is chosen");
};
```

This works fine at least in Titan TTCN. you can find more info about Titan [here](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.titan).

Gustavo.